Find angular speed of a particle having velocity $\bf{v} = \omega\bf{k} \times \bf{r}$ (Tom Apostol's Calculus vol 1, ex. $14.19.18$)
I need to prove that the angular speed $|\frac{d\theta}{dt}|$ of a particle moving in space with the velocity vector $\bf{v} = \omega\bf{k} \times \bf{r}$ is $\omega$, but I get actually $\theta' = \sqrt{\omega^2 - \frac{\omega^2p^2}{r^2}}$.
The procedure I used is:
$$\textbf{r} = r\cos\theta(t)\textbf{i}  + r\sin\theta(t)\textbf{j}+q(t)\textbf{k}$$
$$\textbf{v} = \textbf{r'}= (r'\cos\theta(t) - r\sin\theta(t)\theta'(t))\textbf{i} + (r'\sin\theta(t)+r\cos\theta(t)\theta'(t))\textbf{j} + q'(t)\textbf{k}$$
We know that $\textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{k} = 0 \implies qq' = 0 \implies q(t) = const$. Let then $q(t) = p$.
We also know that $\textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{r} = 0$. From that we have
$$r\cos\theta(t)(r'\cos\theta(t) - r\sin\theta(t)\theta'(t)) + r\sin\theta(t)(r'\sin\theta(t)+r\cos\theta(t)\theta'(t)) = rr' = 0 \implies r' = 0 \implies r = const$$
Then we have that $$\textbf{v} = -r\sin\theta(t)\theta'(t)\textbf{i} + r\cos\theta(t)\theta'(t)\textbf{j}$$. That means that $\|\textbf{v}\|^2 = r^2\theta'^2(t)$. We also know that $\|\textbf{v}\|^2 = \|\omega \textbf{k}\|^2\|\textbf{r}\|^2 - (\omega \textbf{k} \cdot \textbf{r})^2 = \omega^2 r^2 - \omega^2 p^2$.
From the above I get $\theta' = \sqrt{\omega^2 - \frac{\omega^2p^2}{r^2}}$, but the exercise asks us to prove that it's $\omega$. Did I make a mistake somewhere or I should have assumed that $p = 0$, and then I get what the book asks?

Since the velocity vector $\mathbf{v}$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf{k}$, we know that $q'(t) = 0$. Your mistake is in your expression for $\mathbf{v}$ in which you have $p$ as the $z$ component of $\mathbf{v}$. $p$ as you've defined it has units of length, so those units don't work out. The $z$ component of $\mathbf{v}$ should instead be $q'(t)$, which is zero.

Also, what does $\mathbf{kr}$ mean? Is that supposed to be a dot product?

@JohnBarber Yes, thanks, I fixed those typos. However, the end result is the same, since on the paper I didn't have the typo...

I think the problem is that based on your initial definition of $\mathbf{r}$, ${|\mathbf{r}|}^2 \neq r^2$. In fact, $|\mathbf{r}|^2 = r^2 + p^2$. If you instead use this expression later when you have $|\mathbf{r}|^2$, you'll get the right answer.

@JohnBarber Yes, you're right. Thanks! Can you please just write that as an answer, so I can close the question?

Based on your initial definition
\begin{equation}
\textbf{r} = r\cos\theta(t)\textbf{i}  + r\sin\theta(t)\textbf{j}+q(t)\textbf{k}\, ,
\end{equation}
where $q(t) = p$, we have ${\|\textbf{r}\|}^2 = r^2 + p^2$ instead of ${\|\textbf{r}\|}^2 = r^2$. Using the correct expression for ${\|\textbf{r}\|}^2$ later yields the correct answer:
\begin{equation}
\|\textbf{v}\|^2 = \|\omega \textbf{k}\|^2\|\textbf{r}\|^2 - (\omega \textbf{k} \cdot \textbf{r})^2 = \omega^2 (r^2 + p^2) - \omega^2 p^2 = \omega^2 r^2
\end{equation}
